# Can you provide feedback on my approach to proving that $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ is denumerable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, self-learning

**Theorem** $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ is denumerable.

*proof*. Define $f(n,k) = 2^n(2k+1)$, $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$. Choose two distinct pairs $(n_1,k_1)$ and $(n_2,k_2)$ from $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f(n_1,k_1) = f(n_2,k_2)$, which is equivalent to $2^{n_1}(2k_1+1) = 
2^{n_2}(2k_2+1)$. By trichotomy, either $n_1 > n_2$ or $n_1 < n_2$ since our hypothesis rules out $n_1 = n_2$. Assume $n_1 > n_2$, and by symmetry the other case will follow. Then $2^{n_1-n_2}(2k_1+1)= (2k_2+1)$, a contradiction. By Trichotomy either $k_1 > k_2$ or $k_1 < k_2$ since our hypothesis rules out $k_1 = k_2$. Assume that $k_1 > k_2$, then $n_1 < n_2$, another contradiction. The case where $k_1 < k_2$ follows by the same argument.

All natural numbers are of the form $2^{n}(2k+1)$ where $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus we obtain a bijection between $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Is it rigorous enough, does it cover all possible cases, did I make loose assumptions etc, I'm just a highschooler self learning real analysis from Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis* book so all constructive feedback will be appreciated

Comment: That should work. However, the reason why $2^{n_1-n_2}(2k_1+1)=(2k_2+1)$ is a contradiction is simply because if $n_1 > n_2$ we simply have an even number on the left side and an uneven number on the right side which is impossible. No need to complicate that argument further

Comment: LegNai , how about this line, I have a pretty bad feeling about it 
>Assume that $k1>k2$
, then $n1<n2$
, another contradiction..

Comment: Wait, it is not fully correct:
You need to be careful at the beginning: If you count $0\in\mathbb{N}$, then it cannot be represented as $2^n(2k+1)$. However, if you count $0\notin\mathbb{N}$, then you cannot represent $1$. In the latter case you could rephrase $f$ to be $f(n,k)=2^{n-1}(2k-1)$ to make it work.

Comment: Yes this works, as $k_1>k_2$ implies that $2^{n_1-n_2}<1$, so $n_1<n_2$. However the reverse case does NOT follow because of the same argument: If $k_1<k_2$, then $n_1>n_2$ which is just the assumption.
Thus, I would simply argue with the divisors: If $n_1>n_2$, then the left side is divisible by $2$ while the right side is not -> contradiction

Comment: You can use $f(n,k) = 2^n(2k+1)-1$ to represent $0$ if you assume $0 \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @aerile: indeed! The way I remember your formula is that $(n, k)$ maps to the number whose binary expansion has $k$ in binary, followed by a $0$ followed by $n$ in unary.

Comment: Instead, try $$f(n,m)=m+\dfrac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}{2},$$ you will see a classical zigzag counting for the grid $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. Need to take $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$

Comment: Actually I like @HeadlessHorseman.7 function better, as it becomes immediately clear and seems more intuitive. For the zigzag counting it is kinda hard to visualize how that works directly from the function itself (at least for someone relatively new at this topic). Nevertheless another good option

Comment: The assumption that $(n_1, k_1)\neq(n_2, k_2)$ does *not* rule out $n_1=n_2$, and it does *not* rule out $k_1=k_2$. It only rules out that both of those happen *at the same time*.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which is less creative  can be using Schröder–Bernstein theorem.
Obviously there’s an injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $. Now consider this function from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. $f(n,k)=p^{n}q^{k}$, where $p$ and $q$ are coprime natural numbers (for example two distinct prime numbers). We see that $f$ is one-to-one and using Schröder–Bernstein, we get the result.

Schröder–Bernstein theorem: [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem#:~:text=In%20set%20theory%2C%20the%20Schr%C3%B6der,function%20h%20%3A%20A%20%E2%86%92%20B](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20set%20theory%2C%20the%20Schr%C3%B6der,function%20h%20%3A%20A%20%E2%86%92%20B).